# Sending name array in PHP Mail

Tags: php, email, post, explode

I'm using PHP's Mail function to send emails to individuals. I wanted an easy way to customize the greeting name in the email, so i created a form where there is a comma separated list of emails and a comma separated list of names, and they get posted and mailed via PHP.

However, every time I send it, the name spits out the entire array of names, and not the ONE value I specify. I've been working on this for an hour now and cannot for the life of me see where the problem is.. its such simple code! Here is the code let me know if you see any glaring errors.

```
$to_emails = $_POST['to_emails'];
$to_names = $_POST['to_names'];
$from_email = $_POST['from_email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$explode_emails = str_replace(" ", "", explode(",",$to_emails));    
$explode_names = explode(",",$to_names);

$email_array = array();

$i=0;
foreach($explode_names as $e) {
    $name = $e;
    $to      = $explode_emails[$i];
    $subject = $subject;
    $message = $name.",\r\n".$message;
    $headers = 'From: '.$from_email . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '.$from_email . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);        
    echo "<font color='#FF0000'>".$i." Emailed: ".$name." : ".$to."</font><br />";
    $i++;

}


<form method="post">
To Emails (comma separated)
<input type="text" name="to_emails" value="">
<br /><br />
To Names (comma separated)
<input type="text" name="to_names" value="">
<br /><br />


From
<input type="text" name="from_email" value="trgentes@gmail.com">
<br /><br />

Subject
<input type="text" name="subject" value="">
<br /><br />

Message
<textarea name="message" rows="5" id="message"></textarea>
<br /><br />

<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Sample input and output would be helpful. For instance, if your input to $to_names is not comma-delimited, it will not get tokenized as you're expecting.

Comment: do a `echo $to_names;` to make sure there isn't thing funky going on with the POST data and that your `,` is actually getting delimited.

Comment: then do a `echo $explode_names[0]` to see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, the data going in is comma delimited.. so forexample emails are "bob@gmail.com, jim@gmail.com" and names are "bob, jim"

Comment: Check the line `$explode_emails = str_replace(" ", "", explode(",",$to_emails)); `. I think you have your replace and explode backwards.

Comment: i know it SHOULD be working because that echo at the end does display the correct output. It says the Email / Name. But in the email to the second person, it will spit out "Bob, Jim, ... rest of message"

Comment: ok will do .. thanks lemme check

Comment: okay i checked the str_replace and explode. its working fine. this is the echo output i get at the end                                     0 Emailed: tory : t@gmail.com
1 Emailed: brian : b@gmail.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. I'm not sure if this exactly answers what you want, but it would send email to all the people specified:

```
$to_emails = $_POST['to_emails'];
$to_names = $_POST['to_names'];
$from_email = $_POST['from_email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$explode_emails = array_map('trim', explode(",", $to_emails));
$explode_names = array_map('trim', explode(",",$to_names));

$recipients = array_combine($explode_emails, $explode_names);

$i=0;
foreach($recipients as $email => $name) {
    $headers = 'From: ' . $from_email;
    $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: " . $from_email;
    $headers .= "\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    $finalMessage = $name . ",\r\n" . $message;

    mail($email, $subject, $finalMessage, $headers);        

    echo "<font color='#FF0000'>" . $i . " Emailed: " . $name . " : " . $email . "</font><br />";

    $i++;
}
```

Here's a quick rundown of the changes I made:

1. `str_replace()` wasn't really needed. `trim()` is a more efficient function to trim leading or trailing whitespace.
2. I merged the email addresses and their corresponding names into an associative array called `$recipients`. This is easier to keep track of than referencing them by a numeric key, and actually associates the data to each other. This also makes looping over them easier to read.
3. I simplified how headers are created. It's easier to add the carriage return `\r\n` at the start of the string, making it easier to read, and less likely to forget one, or leave an extra return on the end.

While the above code will work, I'll also take this opportunity to also warn you of a vulnerability present in your current code: **[Email Header Injection](http://www.damonkohler.com/2008/12/email-injection.html)**.

If an attacker submits content to your form containing the "\r\n" character, they can inject their own headers. Meaning, they could end up sending this email to more people than you want it to go to, or they may inject their own custom body message.

[This example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/228389-preventing-php-mail-header-injections/) should be a good example for you on how to prevent this kind of attack, as its code example highly resembles yours.

You should NEVER trust input sent via $_POST. You should validate the submitted data is in the correct format you expect and does not contain any malicious characters.

Comment: Also, it is being used on a private server. It's not open for access by anyone.. If it was, I would surely do some sql injection prevention. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I take that back... it's not working. Can someone else run this and see if they get the following same problem? The email to the first person works.. it'll say "Brian, this is a message" but the email to the second person will say "Brian, Tory, this is a message", and etc. for the third and fourth person. It keeps adding the previous names in to the email. BUT, it echoes correctly. I am completely baffled.

Comment: Ah, sorry. It was accidentally reassigning the `$message` variable, causing the name to be prepended with each loop. I have edited the above code to fix this issue.

Comment: Just because it's on a private sever or behind a login doesn't mean you should negate validating input. If a user's account becomes compromised and an attacker gains access using their credentials, you suddenly open up your server to all kinds of other attacks. A quick fix for this would be to strip all new line characters from $_POST vars using str_replace.

Comment: Ah, good catch! The $message variable was what was baffling me as well. I'll give the str_replace fix a go. Appreciate your help!